# my container is not accessible to the internet even though security rules are allowing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-security-group

i am having a weird issue of my docker containers not being accessible to the internet. my containers are running and the correct ports have been opened but cant seem to access them.

i am using ports 8080 for jenkins and 8081 for nexus

i have tried removing the containers and reinstalling them, restarted them i have literally spent the whole day trying to fire this out. no idea what could be the issue.

i am expecting to reach the correct application but all i get is:

This site can’t be reached 18.130.249.99 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAsDh.png)
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you open port on aws security-group ?

Comment: Did you map the ports from the host to the container?

Comment: hey yes i have exposed the ports and also mapped them to the ports. let me attach screen grabs

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
eb18cf3d55c0        15625611d6fb        "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   7 seconds ago        Up 6 seconds        8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   confident_snyder
02d85a81d1f6        836c51250912        "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute   8081/tcp              zen_elgamal

Comment: did you open port of firewall on Linux server ? check it ?

Comment: I am running it on Aws I have opened the security rules setting it was working when I installed just the Jenkins container. But after installed nexus too. They both went down

Comment: I have attached images showing the security group rules, and the ports the containers are using

Comment: Looks like you didn't map the ports of the container to the host. what's the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`?

Comment: I agree with @Thilak, when the port is mapped properly the docker shows something like this: 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 80/tcp, so netstat will probably show this problem.

Comment: yes i can see nothing shows when i do netstat -tulpn | grep 8080. how do i map my container to the port number?

Comment: i have mapped my container to the port now i can see the port number is showing with when i run docker ps -a , i ran netstat -tulpn | grep 8081 and can see my container docker proxy is listening. however my contain is still not accessible

Comment: Try both comands inside the remote server, then in your local machine:

telnet localhost 8080
curl http://localhost:8080